# Timeout error connecting to postgres hosted via RDS on Amazon from Node.js app

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to use postgres in a Node.js app. I have created a db instance and I am using pg to connect to it. When I try to connect to it, I get the error:

```
{ Error: connect ETIMEDOUT xxx.xx.xx.xxx:5432
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1097:14)
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: 'xxx.xx.xx.xxx',
  port: 5432 }
```

I have made sure that the database is public. I've search for this error on SO and google and duckduckgo and can't find a similar error.

I've double and triple checked that my host, user, database, password, and port are all correct. I'm using the pg documentation [here](https://node-postgres.com/features/connecting) and the aws documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-nodejs.rds.html) to setup my connection.

I would love any insight anyone has to offer.

```
const express = require('express');
const logger = require('morgan');
const helmet = require('helmet');

const { Pool, Client } = require('pg');

const server = express();

server.use(logger('dev'));
server.use(helmet());

const keys = require('./keys/keys');

const pgConfig = {
    host: keys.pgHost,
    user: keys.pgUserName,
    database: keys.pgDBName,
    password: keys.pgUserPW,
    port: keys.pgDBPort
};

const pool = new Pool({ ...pgConfig });

server.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    await pool.connect((err, client, release) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    })

    return res.status(200).send('<h1>Welcome to the server</h1>');
});

module.exports = server;
```

Edit: I was able to connect to the database using pgadmin using the same host, db username and password that is saved in my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. I actually am connecting successfully. I didn't return in `pool.connect()` and that was causing the timeout. I changed it to below and now it is consoling out "no error" and no connection timeout errors.

```
await pool.connect((err, client, release) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        return console.log("no error");
    }
})
```